# how to increase navigation pane size in preference window in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to increase the size of the left navigation pane in the preferences window(the white background one) so that it shows my tool's preferences completely.

As of now a part of it is hidden(full name is mytoolpreference but only mytool is visible whereas preference word is hidden), and I have to increase the navigation pane size manually which I don't want,so please let me know how to increase the navigation pane size.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about Eclipse itself: That's not possible, as the dialog is not part of the extension point (for good reasons).

If that's for your own RCP application: Feel free to sub class and override the preference dialog. However, this is not recommended, as shared Eclipse UI should seldomly be modified (so users of one Eclipse RCP application still feel like home when using another RCP application).

General advice: Avoid enforcement of UI sizes, whenever you can. The operating system and its windowing system will often "override" your planned sizes anyway. So the result of opening that preference dialog may vary wildly under Windows and Ubuntu, for example. Instead try to shorten your label, that solution will then work under all circumstances.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, bananaweizen. i apologise, but i forgot to mention that i have created a customized eclipse product and installed a feature project in it. i have used the org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages extn point in the feature project and added a new preference node in the same preference window. i am not intending to create a new preference window. is this possible? if yes please guide me. thanks in advance.